# SWIG 'cstring.i' Python return byte type instead of string type

Tags: python, swig

I have a C function like

```
int foo(void ** buf, int * buf_size)
```

And I use `cstring.i` to wrap it for use in Python 3. The result of the wrapped Python function is of type string.

Is there a way to get the result as type binary?

Background: The data `buf` gets filled with is msgpack encoded data, so using `str.decode` in Python is not an option. The msgpack implementations for Python only accept binary data.

Comment: Use `cstring_chunk_output` from `cstring.i`. This can be used for return a chunk of binary output. SImilarly `cstring_chunk_output` is the other way

Comment: Using `cstring_chunk_output` also results in function returning a `str`, not`bin`.

Besides, in my case, the size of the data is unknown (therefor the `int * buf_size`. According to the cstring.i documentation, `cstring_output_allocate_size` is the way to go (and works), the only problem is, as stated, that the return in Python is typed as `str`.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to have binary content as a string in Python. Special characters are escaped. Calling tostring on an NumPy array gives you binary output as a string

Comment: True, but the `msgpack-python` library demands byte like data and refuses `str`.  For converting to e.g. `bytearray`, you need to supply an encoding, which either fails or messes up the data. I haven't found any method to convert a `str` just as it is.

Comment: I see. It should be pretty straight forward to get the char* from a SWIG proxy object. I provide an answer later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `%cstring_output_allocate_size` the wrapper function `_wrap_foo` calls `SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize()` which has the following decoding logic:

```
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
#if defined(SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR)
      return PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(carray, (Py_ssize_t)(size));
#else
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03010000
      return PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8(carray, (Py_ssize_t)(size), "surrogateescape");
#else
      return PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(carray, (Py_ssize_t)(size));
#endif
#endif
#else
  return PyString_FromStringAndSize(carray, (Py_ssize_t)(size));
#endif
```

So you can get bytes instead of unicode string by #defining `SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR`. This is documented in http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html so it's an official feature. But since it's a global switch, it's only useful if you want all string parameters to be mapped to bytes. If you need a mix of `str` and `bytes` in your API the only solution I can see is a custom typemap.

Comment: Note that this is a new feature. It is not available in swig 3.0.8, but it is available in swig 3.0.10.

Comment: I hadn't tried this solution since I switched to ctypes (totally sufficient for my case) but I guess this is the way to go. (Late) Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using `ctypes`, with the help of https://github.com/bit-01101/ctypesgen