# SWIG return bytes instead of string with typemap

Tags: python, swig, swig-typemap

I have two functions in my C library:

```
void passBytes(char *data, int size);
void returnBytes(char **data, int *size); //dynamically allocates
```

I successfully implement the wrapper for the first function using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427455/input-python-3-bytes-to-c-char-via-swig):

```
%typemap(in) (char *data, int size) {
  Py_ssize_t len;
  PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input, &$1, &len);
  $2 = (int)len;
}
```

But can't figure out how to implement the second wrapper with [typemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39518594/1665791). Can't use `SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR` because I need mix of `str` and `bytes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) (char **data) (char *temp) {
  $1 = &temp;
}
%typemap(argout) (char **data) {
  if (*$1) {
    $result = PyUnicode_FromString(*$1);
    free(*$1);
  }
}
```

Note that the two typemaps combined do the job. The length is not needed if the character array is null terminated. The parameter `temp` is created and the reference to this is passed to your C function allocating the array.

Comment: Oh, argout... I should've read the docs more thoroughly. Thank you!